# Domain redirect seems to break WP customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I searched for answers and didn't find anything that was exactly the issue I'm dealing with...

We have a domain with the following setup:

- domainname.com/articles (blog / wp -  The site is installed in the root directory, not a subfolder. We set the Reading Settings so the homepage displays the posts on /articles)
- store.domainname.com/landing (store)

If you go to *domainname.com* directly, we have a redirect which takes you to the store landing page.

Problem: In the WP Customizer for our theme (Astra Pro), when it tries to put the site preview in, I believe it is trying to get the site url (domainname.com) and then is getting redirected to the store landing page.

On the Customizer page, the Chrome Console shows an error and lists the store landing page URL as the source.

Is there any way to prevent this redirect issue in the Customizer, and specify that it should stay on the domainname.com?

Comment: What is the site URL set to in _Settings > General_? If your WordPress install is at `domainname.com/articles`, then that should be the Site URL in WordPress, not just `domainname.com`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks. The site is installed in the root directory, not a subfolder. (However, we did set the Reading Settings so the homepage displays the posts on /articles)